# Rails: Virtual Attribute Reader Causing Error During Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.0.3 application. . .

I'm using a virtual attribute in a model to convert a value stored in the database for display based on a user's preference (U.S. or metric units).  I'm doing the conversion in the reader method, but when I test my presence validation I get a NoMethodError because the real attribute is nil.  Here's the code:

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :converted_weight, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.1}

  before_save :convert_weight

  attr_accessor :converted_weight

  def converted_weight(attr)
    self.weight_entry = attr
  end

  def converted_weight
    unless self.user.nil?
      if self.user.miles?
        return (self.weight_entry * 2.2).round(1)
     else
       return self.weight_entry
     end
    else
     return nil
  end
end
...
```

This is the line that's causing the problem:

```
return (self.weight_entry * 2.2).round(1)
```

I understand why self.weight_entry is nil, but what's the best way to handle this?  Should I just throw in an unless self.weight_entry.nil? check in the reader?  Or should I perform this conversion somewhere else? (if yes, where?)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it correct that you want to use two methods with the same name (converted_weight) but different input parameters ("method overloading")?

Comment: My understanding is one is a getter and the other a setter method. From my limited understanding of Rails my setter is probably not required (Rails handles this via the attr_accessor helper). What I do need to do is convert the value from it's metric value (kg) to U.S. units (lbs).  My initial guess was to do this in a virtual attribute's getter method, but it's blowing up during validation when I test for presence of the virtual attribute because there's no weight_entry value yet. At least that's what I think is happening.

Comment: I think I'm getting confused by the naming of `converted_weight`. Could you show your form code? Is `weight_entry` passed by the form and should it get stored in the database?

Comment: Can't figure out how to get a newline in the comments section. See answer below - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done:

Model

```
validates :weight_entry, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.1}

before_save :convert_weight

attr_reader :converted_weight

def converted_weight
  unless self.user.nil?
    unless self.weight_entry.nil?
      if self.user.miles?
        return (self.weight_entry * 2.2).round(1)
      else
        return self.weight_entry
      end
    end
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Form

```
<%= f.label :weight_entry, 'Weight' %><br />
<%= f.text_field :weight_entry, :size => 8, :value => @weight.converted_weight %> <strong><%= weight_units %></strong> (<em>Is this not right? Go to your <%=  link_to 'profile', edit_user_registration_path %> to change it</em>)
```

The `unless.self.weight_entry.nil?` check allows the validation to do it's job.  If anyone knows of a better way to do this I'm open to suggestion.

Thanks!

P.S. The `before_save convert_weight` method converts U.S. units to metric.  I want to store values in the same units consistently so if a user changes her preference later previously stored values don't become invalid.